# Is it possible to split very large RDLs at a specific breakpoint?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I have a very large RDL that prints to a PDF. The generated PDF results in thousands of pages and it's not really possible to reduce the result set.

I've tried many different methods for optimizing the PDF output such as reducing unnecessary formatting, removing all images, using embedded PDF fonts, but my report still takes a very long time to process.

If each one of my records carries an ID beginning with A-Z, is it possible to have the RDL itself trigger multiple *child* RDLs, such that something like all "A" results would be produced, all "B" results would be produced and so on and so forth?

Comment: Have you considered data driven subscription to break it down to a few records per PDF there by each pdf is a managable size?

Comment: I would +1 data driven subscriptions. They should allow you to produce a seperate exported report for each letter for example